# How to get 12.10 fix for PDF Printing Problem (where some pages print blank) in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, printing, pdf

As [documented on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1032537), there is a bug for Ubuntu 12.04 somewhere in the PDF printing stack.  This bug causes some or all pages of the PDF to print blank.  Since this issue doesn't occur in Ubuntu 12.10, it seems no one is interested in fixing the issue on Ubuntu 12.04.

This is a serious issue for me.  My job requires me to print many PDFs sent to me by other people, some of which are effected by this bug (none of the PDFs I create in Ubuntu are effected by this issue).  My current workaround is to open *every single file* in Adobe's PDF Reader in Windows and print them to...wait for it...PDF.  Other than being a huge waste of time, I extremely dislike having to use these two pieces of proprietary software to avoid this bug.

> How can I get the fix in Ubuntu 12.10 for this bug in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not understand what the question actually is.

I am using the Cups PDF package (which you can install via `sudo apt-get install cups-pdf`), which adds a new PDF printer to your printer list and automatically saves all documents printed with it to `/home/<user>/PDF/`.

I have not noticed any bug like the one you described with this, also running Ubuntu 12.04. If you are not using this way it might be a simple solution.

Comment: As I understand it, the problem seems to be with _printing_ (in paper) a PDF (not created in his Ubuntu) from Evince. But "printing" _to_ PDF from Evince with `cups-pdf` might work the same magic as his "printing" to PDF from Acrobat Reader before actually printing to paper.

Comment: Well - as I said, I don't actually understand what his problem exactely is.

Comment: @carnendil Any form of printing (either printing to paper or printing to PDF) exhibited the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem with certain PDF files. Evince only prints the first few pages of such a PDF.

The workaround solution I use is to open the PDF with an alternate PDF viewer which uses a different printing backend. I use Okular for this purpose. I print to file from Okular and then open this new file using Evince. Printing this seems to work fine.

Comment: My workaround was essentially the same, but I used Adobe's PDF view on a Windows computer.